# How to set the <secret> tag in the remote_servers tag?

Tags: clickhouse

experts
I'm trying to configure a cluster setting that does not include < password >.

According to the ClickHouse documentation,( https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/#distributed-clusters )
I think it can be implemented by using the < secret > tag inside the < logs > tag.

However, there is no description for the < secret > tag.

Can I include user information using < secret > tag?

If you have this experience, please share.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any random string. The idea that CH nodes with the same string trust each other.

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/b29e877f269e84ae452c446e70b406a695863470/tests/integration/test_distributed_inter_server_secret/configs/remote_servers_n2.xml

```xml
<clickhouse>
    <remote_servers>
        <secure_disagree>
            <secret>bar_n2</secret>
            <node>
                <host>n1</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </node>
            <node>
                <host>n2</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </node>
        </secure_disagree>
    </remote_servers>
</clickhouse>
```

Comment: thank you.
I understood the answer and it helped me with my setup.
I have another problem, but I'll post that as a different question.
Have a nice day.

Comment: hi.
I entered a string `same_user` in the secret tag.
It seemed to be working fine, but when I checked the next day, an error occurred.
`DB::Exception: Hash mismatch.`
Is there a cause?
All my CH nodes have the same user and password.

Comment: Double check that secret is the same. Double check that CH is the same version.