# Clickhouse Cluster - Can't insert into distributed table without secret under remote_servers

Tags: clickhouse

I have a 3 node cluster

```
<secret>clickhousecluster</secret>
     <shard>
         <replica>
             <host>CHN1</host>
             <port>9000</port>
         </replica>                
     </shard>
     <shard>
         <replica>
             <host>CHN2</host>
             <port>9000</port>
         </replica>                
     </shard>
     <shard>
         <replica>
             <host>CHN3</host>
             <port>9000</port>
         </replica>                
     </shard>
```

I created a distributed table:

```
CREATE TABLE db1.hosts_distr(
    `timestamp` DateTime CODEC(Delta(4), ZSTD(1)),
    `host` LowCardinality(String),`message` String    
)
ENGINE = Distributed('cluster1', 'db1', 'hosts', rand());
```

Everything works fine if I add secret but without this whatever I try inserts only inserts locally while error log is reporting:
`` <Error> Access(user directories): from: 192.168.63.111, user: default: Authentication failed: Code: 192. DB::Exception: There is no user `default` in local directory. (UNKNOWN_USER) ``

I tried default user, then created another user with xml file after that tried crating user using sql with all required privs on cluster, individual nodes and database / tables. The only time it works is when I add <secret>.

Is it possible to exclude secret and just use a user account (with same password) present on all nodes for communication.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197533/how-to-set-the-secret-tag-in-the-remote-servers-tag

Comment: thanks Vitos, but I am trying not to use secret, instead just use a user create via sql or xml.

Comment: If you were using the classic way - just put the default user and his password on each shard definition in remote servers.

Comment: <shard>
 <replica>
  <host>server1.example.com</host>
  <port>9000</port>
  <user>default</user>
  <password>use_storong_pass</password>
  <default_database>db1</default_database>
 </replica>
 <replica>
  <host>server2.example.com</host>
  <port>9000</port>
  <user>default</user>
  <password>use_storong_pass</password>
  <default_database>db1</default_database>
 </replica>
</shard>